# Javascript not firing on WordPress search.php

Tags: javascript, wordpress, mobile, nav

Site in question: http://mtthwbsh.com

I'm running two scripts in my footer that a) make that nav sticky at a certain scrollpoint b) toggle the collapsed mobile nav

This works in all iterations of my website except for search results, it appears that the JavaScript is not appending the ID necessary to make the mobile nav appear and I'm not sure why.

Example: http://mtthwbsh.com/?s=test

If you resize the browser, you'll notice the nav disappears instead of collapsing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your Javascript is not firing because of an error, so the script abort.

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'sticky' (main.js:2)
```

The problem is, that you add your sticky-method before the sticky-plugin is loaded. So re arrange your javascripts you have inserted just before the `</body>`:

...

`jquery.sticky.js`

`main.js`

...

but anyway, the `problem` of the disappearing search-box is in your `style.css`:

```
on line 1215:
@media (max-width: 570px) {
...
     #search-form  {
      /* on line 1240 */
       display: none;
     }
...
}
```

Comment: The search form is actually purposefully disappearing at that point as it moves to the collapsed nav at that point. Your answer makes sense and it was sort of what I was getting at but couldn't put my finger on it. Thanks for the tip!

Comment: For some reason rearranging those didn't work. I know this is the answer to my question but am not sure where exactly the problem is happening.

Comment: I see, its still the same error - main.js line 2. If you look into your header, you load jQuery twice (Line: 21 - v.1.8.0 / Line: 27 - v1.8.3). And on your working Script load-posts.js you start with jQuery(document).ready(function($) { - its all a little bit messy with the JS-Files but it may helps.

Comment: Hmm, not seeing the multiple jquery loads on those lines.

Comment: I dont know how you debug your work. If you using Chrome, use the "Inspect Element" on Firefox use the "Web developer Panel" in IE (dont try it). The code is here: <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.0/jquery.min.js"></script> and <script type="text/javascript" src="//mtthwbsh.com/wp-includes/js/jquery/jquery.js?ver=1.8.3"></script>

Comment: The only difference from the working page without any errors and the search.php where it breaks is in the second jQuery-Load `/mtthwbsh.com/wp-includes/js/jquery/jquery.js?ver=1.8.3` remove this and try it again.

Comment: Ah, that was it! It was just the stock WP included jQuery that was being loaded. Thanks!